# A problem of integration on Bessel function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

For a function defined on a plane using polar coordinate $F_{m,k}(\vec{r})=(c_1J_m(kr)+c_2Y_m(kr))e^{im\theta}$, here parameter $k$ is a positive real number and $m$ is a non-negative integer. I found that for any position $\vec{r}$ (except the origin point), this equation holds:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}F_{m,k}(\vec{r}+\vec{\rho})d\alpha=J_0(k\rho)F_{m,k}(\vec{r})$$

using numeric method (i.e. calculating the integration using Mathematica for some specific $k$ and $m$), here $\rho=|\vec{\rho}|$ and $\rho<|\vec{r}|$, $\alpha$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\rho}$. This integration can be considered as averaging on a circle around position $\vec{r}$ with radius $\rho$. But I can not figure out if this equation holds everywhere on the plane and how can I prove it. Is there anybody who can give me some hints on how to prove it?

Comment: Let $\mathcal C$ denote either $J$ or $Y$, then $F_{m, k}(\vec r - \vec \rho)$ is a linear combination of $e^{m i \arg (w - z)} \mathcal C_m(|w - z|)$. By the [addition theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23.E7),
$$e^{m i \arg (w - z)} \mathcal C_m(|w - z|) =
e^{m i \arg w} \sum_{j \in \mathbb Z}
 \mathcal C_{m + j}(|w|) J_j(|z|) e^{j i (\arg w - \arg z)}$$
for $m \in \mathbb Z$ and $|z| < |w|$. Integration leaves only the $j = 0$ term.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks very much for your help. Maybe you could expand your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?